# extremely low p value when running t-tests

Tags: t-test, p-value

I am running some t-tests for unequal variances, unfortunately I cannot add the data here as it contains sensitive information. upon running a those tests, I got a p value of 1x10^-14. while the between groups is starkly different, I am a little concerned about a p value that small. I am working with largely different N values, (group one is 120, group two is 60), but since it is an unpaired test, that shouldn't matter.

I ran these tests in excel, as I don't have access to Jamovi or SPSS from where I work. what I am most nervous about is that Excel messed up somewhere, and I won't catch it.

Any help is appreciated, I am sorry I can't include more info here.

Comment: I wouldn’t take the p-value too literally, but for reasonably large sample sizes with differences that are apparent upon visual inspection, the p-values tend to be small. Download R and give that a whirl if you are skeptical about Excel.

Comment: Alright, that's not a bad idea, although I'll have to go through the IT department to get permission. I assumed the reason it came out like that was due to the different N values. I'll see what I can do to confirm that.

Comment: In Stata, there is a function called [ttesti](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rttest.pdf), which can perform ttest with just sample sizes (which you provided), means, and SDs. If you're comfortable with sharing the means and SDs, I can double check with Stata for you.

Comment: p-values of obviously differing things at $n_{total}=180$ can be that small. @Dave s idea of using real statistics software for comparison is great. Should you find `R` to difficult to deal with as a beginner you might consider `JASP` as a free alternative with a mor common graphical user interface and good explanations on youtube.

Comment: I really appreciate the offer, unfortunately I am unable to share any info with you. Like I said, the data I am working on is very sensitive, and I could potentially face legal charges  for leaking anything, even something as generic as means and SDs

Comment: @Bernhard, I am a little familiar with R, though I usually use MATLAB as it is what I am most familiar with. I appreciate the the help, and I will look into getting permission to download more robust statistical software.

Comment: There also is a lot of online calculators for things like t-tests. I would not cite them or rely on any of them alone, but for crosschecking results of real software they migth suffice w/o download issues? Personally in my office I run R from a USB stick to avoid having to ask each time there is an update. Even RStudio runs well from a USB stick.

Comment: That's an even better idea, downloading some software onto a stick. let me check out some of those online solutions for now, and I'll see if it all comes out right.

Comment: In the unlikely event of everything else breaking, MATLAB as your goto software can certainly calculate t-tests https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ttest2.html

Comment: Yup, I've used matlab for nearly all my statistical work in the past, but now I am in a new workplace, so there goes that. I'll definitely look into getting MATLAB on a stick though, that is a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your group differences are sufficiently blatant, very small $p$ values can easily result. For instance:

[image: plot]

Here, we get $p\approx 2.3\times 10^{-15}$. ("$\approx$" because you shouldn't take this number too seriously.) R code:

```
set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
group_1 <- rnorm(120)
group_2 <- rnorm(60,3,2)
t.test(group_1,group_2,var.equal=FALSE)

plot(c(0,3),range(c(group_1,group_2)),type="n",xlab="",ylab="",las=1,xaxt="n")
axis(1,1:2,paste("Group",1:2))
points(runif(length(group_1),0.7,1.3),group_1,pch=19)
points(runif(length(group_2),1.7,2.3),group_2,pch=19)
```